# Making temp_tablespaces favor certain tablespaces over others

Tags: postgresql

I've got three tablespaces. Two of them are on disks with ~400GiB free, and one is on a disk with ~200GiB free. I want to set up `temp_tablespaces` to use the latter disk less frequently in case I run out of space on it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Say your tablespaces are `ts1`, `ts2`, and `ts3`, where `ts3` is the smaller one.

`ALTER DATABASE your_database SET temp_tablespaces = ts1, ts1, ts2, ts2, ts3`

Looks like duplicate values in the `temp_tablespaces` list are kept, making Postgres more likely to write a temp file those tablespaces, according to weighted random choice. Transactions use the tablespaces sequentially, which also produces roughly the same weighted distribution ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TEMP-TABLESPACES)). So `ts3` should now have about 1/2 the usage as the other two tablespaces.

I'm trying this now for some huge queries. I see 84GiB used on the first two and 40GiB used on the last one.